# Piglatin Conversion Program

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that can convert both from and English sentence into Piglatin and from Piglatin into English.

So far, the English to Piglatin portions are working fine, but I am having trouble converting from Piglatin to English.

```
def eng2Pig(sentence):
sentsplit = sentence.split()
for part in sentsplit:
    print((part[1:] + part[0] + "ay"), end = " ")

def pig2Eng(sentence):
    sentv1 = sentence.replace("ay", "")
    sentsplit = sentv1.split()
    for part in sentsplit:
        print(part[-1] + part[:-1], end = " ")

def aySearch(sentence):
    numwords = len(sentence.split())
    numay = sentence.count("ay ")
    if numwords == numay:
        pig2Eng(sentence)
    else:
        eng2Pig(sentence)

x = input("Enter your sentence: ")
x = x + " "
aySearch(x)
```

I am having troubles converting English words that originally contain ay.  For example, today converted to Piglatin would be odaytay.  However, I am replacing ay with "" to remove the extra added ay.

Perhaps I need to count the number of ay(s) in a word, then based off of that, decide if I want to remove more than one ay.

Thanks -

Good luck

Comment: Don't forget "then" is "enthay" not "hentay".  You normally take all the consonants up to a vowel. "oughthray" not "hroughtay".

Comment: For pig2Eng, remove the trailing two characters instead of using replace.  `sentence[:-2]` vs. `sentence.replace('ay','')`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is doing a replace ("ay", "") will change the word say int s, so it will corrupt your sentence. Here's a better solution.

```
def pig2Eng(sentence):
    eng = ""
    sentsplit = sentence.split()
    for word in sentsplit:
        eng += word[-3:-2] + word[:-3] + " "
    return eng

print (pig2Eng("igpay atinlay siay tupidsay"))
```

Also note that is usually better programming form to return the result rather than printing it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing - this worked well.

```
def eng2Pig(sentence):
    pig = ""
    sentsplit = sentence.split()
    for part in sentsplit:
        pig += (part[1:] + part[0] + "ay" + " ")
    return pig

def pig2Eng(sentence):
    eng = ""
    sentsplit = sentence.split()
    for part in sentsplit:
        eng += (part[-3] + part[:-3] + " ")
    return eng

def aySearch(sentence):
    numwords = len(sentence.split())
    numay = sentence.count("ay ")
    if numwords == numay:
        return pig2Eng(sentence)
    else:
        return eng2Pig(sentence)


def main():
    x = input("Enter your sentence: ")
    x = x + " "
    print(aySearch(x))

main()
```